# How to transform a union of intervals into a disjoint union of intervals

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, induction, real-numbers

Let $([a_i,b_i])_{1\leq i\leq n}$ be a family of closed intervals of $\mathbb{R}$. I want to prove that there exists a family of disjoint intervals $([c_i,d_i])_{1\leq i\leq m}$ for $m\leq n$ such that
$$\bigcup_{i=1}^n[a_i,b_i]=\bigcup_{i=1}^m[c_i,d_i].$$
I've tried to prove this by induction on $n$. For case $n=2$, we can take $c_1=\min(a_1,a_2)$ and $d_1=\max(b_1,b_2)$. Suppose it holds for $n$. Then by the induction hypothesis there exists a family of disjoint intervals $([c_i,d_i])_{1\leq i\leq m}$ for $m\leq n$ such that
$$\bigcup_{i=1}^{n+1}[a_i,b_i]=\bigcup_{i=1}^n[a_i,b_i]\cup[a_{n+1},b_{n+1}]=\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^m[c_i,d_i]\right)\cup[a_{n+1},b_{n+1}].$$
If $\bigcup_{i=1}^m[c_i,d_i]$ and $[a_{n+1},b_{n+1}]$ are disjoint, we are done. I don't know what to do in the case that they aren't disjoint. Any suggestions? Or perhaps hints about a better proof?

Comment: If some intervals are not disjoint, replace them by $[\min(a_i),\max(b_i)]$. It is easy to show that a point belonging to one of the intervals belongs to the replacement.

Comment: @BobbyLaspy Are you proposing to replace every such that $[c_i,d_i]\cap[a_{n+1},b_{n+1}]\ne\emptyset$ by $[\min(c_i,a_{n+1}),\max(d_i,b_{n+1})]$? But then how does disjointness follow?

Comment: You partition the set of intervals in disjoint subsets. Replacing the subsets by single intervals perserves disjointness.

Comment: Maybe note that $E= \bigcup_{i=1}^n [a_i,b_i]$ is a bounded closed set and it contains at most a finite number of points isolated on exactly one side.  Say these are the points $x_1 < x_2 <  \dots < x_m$.  Etc. Maybe?

Answer (score 1):

A slick way to finish your argument is to make some more flexible use of your induction hypothesis.  Keep in mind that you know that *any* union of at most $n$ intervals can be written as a disjoint union of at most $n$ intervals.  You can keep applying this to more collections of $n$ intervals besides just the first $n$ you used.  In particular, for instance, if $m<n$, then you're already done, since you have already reduced down to a union of $m+1\leq n$ intervals.

If $m=n$, then you still need to find a way to reduce the number of intervals by $1$ to apply the induction hypothesis.  In other words, it would be enough to just combine two of your intervals into one.  Can you find a way to do that?

More details are hidden below.

> Since you are assuming your intervals are not disjoint, two of them intersect.  Now by your argument in the case $n=2$ you can replace those two with their union which is a single interval.